# How do I accept and output both Doubles and Ints in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, int, double

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PeopleWeights {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

     final int NUM_VALS = 5;

     int [] personsWeight = new int[NUM_VALS];

     int i = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
     System.out.print("Enter weight " + (i + 1) + ": ");
     System.out.println();
     personsWeight[i] = scnr.nextInt();
     }

     double sumVal = 0.0;

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
        sumVal = sumVal + personsWeight[i];
     }

     double avgVal = 0.0;

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
        avgVal = sumVal / NUM_VALS;
     }

     double maxVal = 0.0;

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
        maxVal = personsWeight[0];
        if (maxVal < personsWeight[i]) {
           maxVal = personsWeight[i];
        }
     }

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(personsWeight[1] + " " + personsWeight[2] + " " 
     + personsWeight[3] + " " + personsWeight[4] + " " + personsWeight[5]);
//I know that this can be cleaner but this is where the 
//problem occurs with a InputMismatchException. 
//I know it's caused by the double being introduced 
//but don't know how to fix it.


     System.out.println("Total weight: " + sumVal);

     System.out.println("Average weight: " + avgVal);

     System.out.println("Max weight: " + maxVal);

     return;
  }
}
```

The inputs are as follows:
236 ,
89.5 ,
142 ,
166.3 ,
93 .

I want to handle the output numbers just as they are input. Double or Int.

Is there anyway I can make the Array accept both types of numbers in the scanner or would I have to resort another way that it works?

Comment: The normal thing would be to treat everything as a `double`.  You can store 236 in a `double` with no problem.  Why would it matter that you keep it as an integer?  What unwanted consequence would there be to keeping it as a double?

Comment: Also, the `InputMismatchException` is happening way up on this line: `personsWeight[i] = scnr.nextInt();` and has nothing to do with the array type.  It has to do with using `nextInt()` on input that has a decimal in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine initially if the inputted number is Double or Integer using `hasNextInt()` or `hasNextDouble()` methods of `Scanner` class.

```
if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
    int n = scnr.nextInt();
    //your code to handle `integer` case
}
else if(scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
    double d = scnr.nextDouble();
    //your code to handle `double` case
}
```

FYI, you can also keep everything as `double`. It will handle both `int`s and `double`s and will execute without any error.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it for me. Simply looking if it was an int or double is all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

An array can define only one type, you can define `double` there, like `double [] personsWeight = new double[NUM_VALS];` and when you input an `int` type, like `236`, it will be accepted as a `double` into Array, output as `double` too.

Comment: If there were a good reason, you _could_ have multiple types in an array by making it `Object[]` (or in this case `Number[]`), and the elements could be either `Double` or `Integer` (the _boxed_ versions of the primitive types).  Here, of course, there's no reason to.  But the ability to have multiple types in an array can be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think to solve this is to take in String objects from the `Scanner` and then convert them to their actual type (you can detect that it's a double if the String contains a period) when you need to use their value for any calculation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list of numbers that all represent the same kind of value (such as weight, money amount, test score, etc.), pick one type that's appropriate for all the values that you'd want to handle.  For weight, assuming you want to handle non-integers, choose a floating-point type (i.e. `double`).  For money, you might choose `BigDecimal`; for test scores, you might choose `int` unless you expect someone might get half a point deducted for something, then you'd choose `double`.  The point is, there is almost *never* a reason to keep different numeric types for the same kind of value.

There is almost *never* a reason to care about what format the input is in--i.e. do you really care whether a weight in the input has a decimal point or not?  No, you only care about the value itself.  This confuses some newer programmers--they equate the value of the number with its representation as a string.  But almost always, only the value matters.  There's no difference between the numbers 236, 236.0, 236.00000, 2.36e2, and 0xec--the value is the same, and the representation doesn't matter.  [Yes, I know that if you use these different forms in your Java program, some will be treated as `int` and some as `double`, which could make a difference.  But the numbers here are in the input file, not in the code.]

So just make the weight a `double` and don't worry about integers.

```
 double[] personsWeight = new double[NUM_VALS];

 int i = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
     System.out.print("Enter weight " + (i + 1) + ": ");
     System.out.println();
     personsWeight[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
 }
```